# Parsing JSON using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, ios6, nsjsonserialization

I am currently going through the Pragmatic iOS 6 book, and am having trouble understanding the following line of code explained in chapter 3 under the section about GCD:

```
    NSJSONSerialization *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
    //... some code here
    NSArray *tweets = (NSArray *) jsonResponse; //<-- this line
```

Is it saying that the `NSJSONSSerialization` object could automatically return an instance of NSSArray, which is then stored in the `tweets`?  I checked the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but only saw items on restrictions using `NSJSONSerialization`, but not what objects it could then get converted to.

Thanks!

Comment: Read the Overview section for NSJSONSerialization in the [reference docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010946).

Comment: More specifically, see what it says about the supported top level objects. Those are the possible return values of the `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` method.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the (quite simple) JSON syntax diagram to understand what JSON is and how it represents your data.  You can't understand what you're doing with JSON unless you understand the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSJSONSerialization can take a chunk of JSON data and turn into objects and it can do the same in the other direction that is by taking objects and converting them into the JSON data.

For easy understanding of NSJSONSerialization and interaction with Twitter, i would recommend you to use [THIS](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-quick-tip-interacting-with-web-services/) and [THIS](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_twitter-framework_twrequest/) tutorials.

Hope this helps!